# Problems using nested dynamic forms in yii2

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-extension

I'm trying to use nested dynamic forms using this [yii2 widget](https://github.com/wbraganca/yii2-dynamicform)  and following this [guide](https://github.com/wbraganca/yii2-dynamicform/wiki/Nested-Forms-Example) but whenever I try to have a second dynamic form nested in the first form I get an error stating

```
TypeError
Argument 1 passed to DOMDocument::importNode() must be an instance of DOMNode, null given
```

If I remove the the `<?php DynamicFormWidget::begin([...]):?>` and `<?php DynamicFormWidget::end()?>` the page loads (without the second dynamic form's functionality).

I here is the section of my view that deals with the nested dynamic forms

```
<?php
    $form = ActiveForm::begin(['id'=> 'dynamic-form']);
    ?>

<?php DynamicFormWidget::begin([

            'widgetContainer' => 'dynamicform_wrapper',

            'widgetBody' => '.container-room-items',

            'widgetItem' => '.room-item',

            'limit' => 10,

            'min' => 1,

            'insertButton' => '.add-room',

            'deleteButton' => '.remove-room',

            'model' => $rooms[0],

            'formId' => 'dynamic-form',

            'formFields' => [
                'name',
                'description',
                'price',
                'room_capacity',
                'area'
            ],

        ]); ?>


        <table>
            ...
            <td>
                <?php foreach ($rooms as $indexRoom => $room): ?> 
                    ...
                    <?php DynamicFormWidget::begin([

                        'widgetContainer' => 'dynamicform_inner',

                        'widgetBody' => '.container-bed-items',

                        'widgetItem' => '.bed-item',

                        'limit' => 4,

                        'min' => 1,

                        'insertButton' => '.add-bed',

                        'deleteButton' => '.remove-bed',

                        'model' => $room_beds[$indexRoom][0],

                        'formId' => 'dynamic-form',

                        'formFields' => [
                            'bed_type_id',
                            'capacity'
                        ],

                    ]); ?>

                    <table>...</table>

                    <?php DynamicFormWidget::end(); //closing inner widget... errors happens on this line?>

                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </td>
        </table>
        <?php DynamicFormWidget::end(); ?>

    </div>
```

Not sure what's missing. Would greatly appreciate any help with this, thanks.

Comment: you are assigning `'formId' => 'dynamic-form'` for all the forms inside the `foreach` ? try appending a counter with the id

Answer (score 0):

You are missing html tags with classes configured in widget. Something like this:

```
<div class="container-room-items">
   <div class="room-item">
     <table>
     ...
   </div>
</div>
```

Also, you need buttons for insert/delete with configured classes.